# Changing permalink stops me from creating webpages

Tags: permalinks, apache, mod-rewrite

I've just created a new WordPress site. When changing the permalink structure I cannot create or edit pages. I do have mod_rewrite enabled but alas still get errors. How can I fix this? I've had this error before with mod_rewrite enabled but can't remember for the life of me how I fixed this, any ideas?

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What happens exactly? Do you get an error or something?

Comment: @MrWhite Cant create pages or edit them. Get a "Publishing Failed" error.

Comment: @MrWhite Hey, still can't use wordpress without a custom permalink. I've done everything right with mod_rewrite going by everything says online but still nothing? What do I do?

Comment: Literally cant do anything with my site. Cant edit home page, cant create a post or a page, nothing.

Comment: Can you _view_ your site using the desired permalinks? Have you tried _resetting_ permalinks in the WP config?  Please add the contents of your `.htaccess` file to your question.

Comment: @MrWhite I've reset the permalinks, created pages with easy, can view them but when I set a custom permalink, cant create any or view any, get a 404 error. Here is my .htaccess contents https://bin.privacytools.io/?cde04030e0f8c454#n1qpvfjodAA6M+scaTmCyr5o/03KXzt0RmE50DLrDwk=